# Inverse of a matrix is expressible as a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that if A is invertible, then there exists a polynomial $p$, such that $A^{-1}=p(A)$

Thus far:

Let $W$ denote the $k$ dimensional A-cyclic subspace spanned by a vector $v$.

Then, $I_n=\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_{i}A^i$ for some scalar $a_i$.

What I want to do is multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$, so that way it just falls into my hands, but Im not sure that is 'legal'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) tells you that $p(A)=0_{n\times n}$ for some polynomial $p(x)$, where $p(x)=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n\left(a_kx^n\right)$.

Since $a_0=(-1)^n\det(A)\neq 0$ you can get something like what you got in your question, only without the zero power problem.

Comment: The terms of the polynomial have different degrees depending on $k$, $p(x)=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n\left(a_kx^k\right)$. By linear dependence of $I,A,A^2,...,A^{n^2}$, one can conclude the existence of such a polynomial with degree less or equal $n^2$ without invoking Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: @Git Gud 
I saw a question that asks in the first part "If $AB=BA$ prove that for any 2 polynomials $f$ and $g$, we have $f(A)g(B)=g(B)f(A)$. I did that, and the second part asked to prove that $A^{−1}=p(A)$ for some polynomial with complex coefficients. So how can I use part 1 to prove part 2? Or are they not related to each other ?

Comment: @FareedAF I think that merits its own question. Be careful, though. Nothing is what you said ensures that $A$ is invertible.